# convert gregorian to hijri date in RTF Template

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ms-word, rtf, bi-publisher

I have a requirement to get arabic hijri date in a BI publisher report. So after building the RTF template 
I need to convert gregorian to hijri date in RTF Template using xdo or xslt

Regards,
Rachit

Answer (score 0):

these 2 links will help you :
first learn how you convert from a query gregorian to hijri date

[converting](http://ksadba.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/convert-between-gregorian-hijrah-calendars-using-oracle-to_date/)

then in this link you will be able to convert sql statment into xdoxslt 
[xdoxslt](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E10415_01/doc/bi.1013/e12187/T421739T481158.htm)

Comment: Hi, nls_calendar in our database is gregorian. So i used following tag to display Date "<?xdofx:to_char(CreationDate1,'day dd month yyyy','nls_calendar=''English Hijrah''')?>" but its not working